# what's difference between schema and documents in Graphql?

Tags: graphql, code-generation

what's the difference between schema and documents in Graphql?

schema is like this:

```
type Query {
   fo: String
}
```

but the document is like:

```
query SomeQuery {
  foo {
    bar
  }
}
```

the spec is really confusing https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Language.Document

I always use schema but for client-side type generation in graphql-code-generator it needs document file. https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/getting-started/documents-field

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A document is really any string containing valid GraphQL syntax. According to the [spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Language.Document), a document contains one or more definitions, where a definition could be:

an operation definition

```
query UsersQuery {
  users {
    id
    email
  }
}
```

a fragment definition

```
fragment UserFragment on User {
  id
  email
}
```

a type system definition

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  email: String!
}
```

a type system extension

```
extend type User {
  name: String
}
```

Operation and fragment definitions are known as *executable definitions*. Documents sent to a GraphQL service must only contain executable definitions. Type system definitions and extensions are used in describing a schema -- that's why we commonly call them Schema Definition Language (SDL). A schema is a GraphQL service's "collective type system capabilities" -- it's basically a collection of types and directives that represent everything your GraphQL service can do.

A schema may be described using type system definitions, but it's not really accurate to say that the type definitions *are* the schema because the schema itself also includes the actual field resolution logic as well.